# Getting the bellow error in Terraform - My dynamodb table have 2 columns in that one is list, hence not required the Range_Key

Tags: terraform

Error: Invalid value for module argument

on main.tf line 20, in module "dynamoDBItem":
20:   table_global_secondary_index = each.value.table_global_secondary_index != null ? each.value.table_global_secondary_index : []

The given value is not suitable for child module variable
"table_global_secondary_index" defined at
modules/dynamoDBItem/variables.tf:85,1-40: incorrect list element type:
attribute "range_key" is required.

The pipelines are failing due to this error - because of this range key issue

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your table_global_secondary_index expects a range_key attribute which is missing. You need to either provide this attribute or make it optional. If range_key is optional, adjust your variable definition like so:

```
variable "table_global_secondary_index" {
  type = list(object({
    name               = string
    hash_key           = string
    range_key          = optional(string)
    projection_type    = string
    non_key_attributes = list(string)
  }))
  default = []
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but getting this error - Error: [0m[0m[1mOptional object type attributes are experimental[0m